# Which are the most intuitive and easiest SDKs to develop mobile phone application?

Tags: mobile-phones

Apart from Windows Mobile, Android and Iphone are there any other SDKs to build applications really quick and simple? The SDK should support nice animation APIs.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt is often used to create mobile applications.  Important to know is that Nokia bought the creators of Qt (TrollTech) a few years ago, see also the [qt homepage](http://qt.nokia.com/products/).

Comment: Hi Patrick, are there any screencasts for developing simple applications on Qt. That can really ease out the learning process. Qt looks good.

Comment: Sorry Nitesh, can't help you with that.